# How can I select only one Checkbox in a dynamic view

Tags: android, checkbox, checkboxlist

I have a screen that add dynamically a row with two textView and one CheckBox. My problem is that I only want that the user could check one, and the others have to be uncheck. If the user push another checkbox, enable this and disable all the other checkbox. I've test some things but I don't get the functionality that I want.

I can't change the configuration from checkbox to radioButton and I have to use the method that I'm using:

```
private selected_position = -1;

protected void addGreetingToListView(final GreetingListJson greetings) {
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_greetings_settings_row, greetingListView, false);
        row.setTag(greetings);

        playButton = (ToggleButton) row.findViewById(R.id.detail_play_greeting);            
        TextView greetingName = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.greetingTitle);
        greetingName.setDuplicateParentStateEnabled(true);
        TextView greetingDescription = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.greetingDescription);
        greetingDescription.setDuplicateParentStateEnabled(true);

        checkBox = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.checkBox_greeting_list);
        checkBox.setTag(greetings);


        checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick (View view) {

                if (((CheckBox) view).isChecked())
                {
                    selected_position= greetingListView.getChildCount();
                }
                else
                {
                    selected_position=-1;
                }           
            }

        });


                greetingName.setText(greetings.Name);
                greetingDescription.setText(greetings.Description);


            row.setOnClickListener(this);
            row.setOnLongClickListener(this);
            row.setFocusable(true);


            greetingListView.addView(row);

    }
```

The XML of the Checkbox:

```
   <CheckBox
         android:id="@+id/checkBox_greeting_list"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
```

Comment: maybe use a radiobutton ?

Comment: How many dynamic rows can be generated( a rough figure )...?

Comment: I can't use radiobutton, Unlimited rows.

Comment: if unlimited rows then you should go for listView.

Comment: I can't use a listView, because the layout have other elements and all the screen has a scroll view.

Comment: You can put all the checkboxes in an array. Every time a checkbox is checked, iterate over the array to uncheck other checkboxes.

Comment: @shhp can you give me a short piece of code, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, declare an `ArrayList` in the class:

```
ArrayList<CheckBox> mCheckBoxes = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();
```

Then in `addGreetingToListView` add every new checkbox to `mCheckBoxes` and modify the click listener of the checkbox:

```
checkBox.setTag(greetings);

mCheckBoxes.add(checkBox);
checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick (View view) {

            if (((CheckBox) view).isChecked())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < mCheckBoxes.size(); i++) {
                     if (mCheckBoxes.get(i) == view)
                         selected_position = i;
                     else 
                         mCheckBoxes.get(i).setChecked(false);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                selected_position=-1;
            }           
        }

    });
```

Comment: With this code I can't select any row now, You click in the checkbox but don't enable... Only the last row I can checked

Comment: I don't get "You click in the checkbox but don't enable". What do you mean?

Comment: I mean that when I push the checkbox, doesn't show me the tick enable. For example, at the moment, I have six checkboxes, With this code, The first five I never can select it, only the last one is possible

Comment: Can you post some images to elaborate what you want?

Comment: I'm Sorry, but stackoverflow don't let me post images... Imagine some rows with his checkbox. When I push one, the checkbox is not put enable, always is not enable, make sense?